# Linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore against Oracle

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq2db

I don't understand why linq2db is not generating the correct SQL string for this query against Oracle, and it is working perfectly against SQLServer.

```cs
string idUser="U1";
await context.Users.ToLinqToDbTable().Where(u=>u.IdUser == idUser).FirstOrDefaultAsyncLinqToDB();
```

Always returns null. However, it works if el value used directly:

```cs
await context.Users.ToLinqToDbTable().Where(u=>u.IdUser == "U1").FirstOrDefaultAsyncLinqToDB();
```

Looking at the logs, el SQL statement generated is like this:

```sql
--  Oracle Oracle11
DECLARE @idUser Varchar2(8) -- String
SET     @idUser = 'U1'

SELECT
u.IdUser,
etc..
FROM
    USERS u
WHERE
    u.IDUSER = :idUser
```

Why is it generating T-SQL code and not Oracle code (the context is initialized with .UseOracle())?
Thanks

Comment: Please post table definition, especially column type `IdUser`

Comment: Anyway it is not Transact SQL code, it is just debug log. Parameters are formatted in SQL Server way.